# Mixed Content Error in JS file- PHP Quiz Software based on Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, ssl

I ran a quiz website which is based on PHP-Codeigniter, recently I have added an SSL certificate. I have changed the base_url to start with https, everything was ok unless I started creating a quiz for that js need to do some function but all browser is blocking it.

Error detail:
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://website.com/quiz/index.php/quiz/add_new' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://website.com/quiz/index.php/qbank/get_level_question/0/2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
send @ jquery.js:2
jquery.js:2

Note: I can't access the link http link directly to change it to https. 
I don't know much about servers/php. I access by website via Cpanel. I can copy and paste codes:)

Comment: The quiz software can be found here- https://git.code.sf.net/p/savsoft-quiz-v2-0/code savsoft-quiz-v2-0-code

Comment: replace the link with `//website.com/quiz/index.php/qbank/get_level_question/0/2` to avoid any protocols conflicts .

Comment: Your first request was done using HTTP**S** while the script uses HTTP (note the missing "S") which leads to this "Mixed content" issues. The additional "S" stands for "Secure",  which means that the communication is encrypted. That error is a security measurement. Just ensure that other traffic is done over HTTP**S** if your page is loaded over HTTP**S**